# Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [X.X.X.X]. Assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permissions

Tags: centos-7, zabbix

I have a Zabbix configuration problem here in the company a few days ago. I'm having this error on the hosts page in the Settings portion. I have already done several tests, being:

1. Agent and Server Ports Release (Firewall Disabled)
2. I changed the settings of agent.config and server.config.
3. I disabled SELINUX.

Agent and Server Ports Release (Firewall Disabled)
I changed the settings of agent.config and server.config.
I disabled SELINUX.
If you can help me thank you, I only need this communication so I can proceed with the finalization of the installation.

> Error: Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [X.X.X.X].
>   Assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permissions.

I already looked for solutions in google but I did not find answers

**UPDATE:** I noticed that the server apparently has some network problem. I have managed to install normal zabbix using yum in Centos 7. However, the server is taking too long to ping google.com and is missing the settings in the resolv.conf file.

I do not know what this network problem can be, I'm a beginner in linux and I'm having a bit of trouble correcting this without having to configure a new server.

**UPDATE 2:** I identified that the server did not contain the google DNS (8.8.8.8) configured in: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 so I added this registry and it solved the network problem, now it's ping google.com , before of this was only the internal DNS of the company. But the initial problem still persists and I think there may be some relationship with network configurations

Configs: [SERVER CONFIG](http://txt.do/d3i6f), [AGENT CONFIG](https://textuploader.com/d3i67)

Comment: check both side ip address , to client site set zabbix-server ip on zabbix-agent config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zabbix agent configuration file must allow connections from the server - see the `Server` configuration parameter.

In this particular case, your agent is more recent than the server (`Message from ... is missing header`). Try with an version agent that matches the server.

Comment: Your answer did not help much, I already checked these settings, could be more specific?

Comment: Please describe in detail what exactly you checked, and what was observed. If that does not highlight the cause, consider increasing agent log level - then it will print messages about incoming connections, including the IP address it sees. You might have a misconfiguration, unexpected outgoing IP or NAT, among other possible causes.

Comment: So, I checked the port settings on windows, I got to disable the firewall and Kaspersky that was running.

In addition, I noticed that when I telnet from port 10050 from the server to the agent it connects but then returns the message: "Connection closed by foreign host." next, I disabled Firewalld in CENTOS 7 and confirmed the SELINUX disabled again.

The agent log has the following information: [Agentd log](http://txt.do/ditwv)

Comment: In this particular case, your agent is more recent than the server (`Message from ... is missing header`). Try with an version agent that matches the server.

Comment: Hello, I was able to resolve adjusting version of Agent with that of Server, they really were different. Although I managed to resolve before your response, I approved of it being correct. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score -1):

This error is not a permission error or a server side error. this one related to network hops, First enable debug level in your zabbix agent conf, nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf UN-comment this line and change it to number 4 Debug Level=4 then restart your agent service tail the log file tail -f /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log if your log shows any rejected IP hop, you need to white-list that IP on your agent conf file in two places. server=zabbixserverIP,LasthopIP ServerActive=zabbixserverIP,LasthopIP

in this case main thing is, in your zabbix serverIP range what is the first network hop in your routing, that IP you need to white-list.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not entirely correct, and listing multiple addresses when only one would be needed could be adding to the confusion.